# Error undefinde reference

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, soil

I'm trying to use the SOIL (simple opengl image library) in SDL, at compile time (using CodeBlocks in WindowsXP) is giving the following error 57 times:

`` G:\mingw32\lib\libSOIL.a (SOIL.o) : SOIL.c || undefined reference to `glTexParameteri @ 12 '| ``.

I think the problem is in OpenGL, however, the functions that are not finding SOIL, are available and working on my project.
I am importing the heading `soil.h` and put the`libSoil.a` along with the SDL libs.

The method that is giving error:

```
int w, h;
unsigned char* image =
    SOIL_load_image("img.png", &w, &h, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
```

Comment: You need to link with the OpenGL library as well. Append e.g. `-lGL` to your build command.

Comment: linker options: ```-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2```, librarys: ```opengl32 glu32 libSOIL``` of my project.

Comment: Please give the exact command you type to compile your project ?

Comment: I use codeblocks, and not by compiler command line. And the links and libraries are the ones i wrote. If even asism be a command line to compile, I'm sorry it did not know.